# How to initialize a reference field without a value?

Tags: rust

If I have structs `A` and `B`:

```
struct B {}

struct A<'a> {
  id: i32,
  b: &'a B
}

impl A<'_> {
  fn new() -> A {
    id: 3,
    b: // I have no B at the moment, how to create a A without B?
  }
}
```

I would like to create `A`, then assign `&B` to it later.

Comment: When a field's value is optional, use an [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/index.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use [`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/)? Rust doesn't have null, thankfully.